# HBS module on Express 3.0 adding text to the generated HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, express, handlebars.js

I'm getting this bug that I'm fairly confused about. I'm running an express 3.0.6 app using the [hbs package](https://github.com/donpark/hbs) for handlebars templating. 
I'm trying to create blocks for the scripts and stylesheets for each view, based off [this example](https://github.com/donpark/hbs/tree/master/examples/extend).

For some reason, whenever I try to use the helper, it adds some numbers (as straight text) to the top of the html file. Even weird, the numbers change upon refreshing, and I have no idea what's wrong or even how to figure out what's going on.

```
blocks = {}
hbs.registerHelper 'extend', (name, context) ->
    block = blocks[name]
    if not block
        block = blocks[name] = []
    block.push(context.fn this)

hbs.registerHelper 'block', (name) ->
    val = (blocks[name] || []).join('\n')
    blocks[name] = []
    return val
```

In the layout.html:

```
 <head>
  {{{block "stylesheets"}}}
  {{{block "javascripts"}}}
 </head>
```

In other views:

```
{{#extend "stylesheets"}}
  <link ... />
{{/extend}}

{{#extend "javascripts"}}
  <script ... 
{{/extend}}
```

In the output html, I get "1 1 ". The 1's sometimes randomly change in value, but there are always x of them, where x is the number of extend tags.

Thanks for any insight/help anyone might be able to give!

EDIT:: 
Also, another thing I noticed is that if I change the block helpers to:

```
  {{{stylesheets}}}
  {{{javascripts}}}
```

the numbers start at 1, and then keep incrementing by 1 each time I refresh the page. I'm not sure what's going on, but hopefully that'll help.

Comment: Just a guess, but getting numbers back like that generally come from how your webservice call formats the data that it returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out in the 'extend' register helper, coffeescript automatically returned the output of the last statement of the method, and that was causing an issue. If I just stick in an extra return statement in there, it worked.